# how to sort Array with UnixTime stamp

Tags: ios, iphone, sorting, nsarray

I want to sort an array by time. But the problem is that the time is in Form UNIX time stamp in the  another array (sub array of array).

here is the format. Please can any one help me in sorting it .

```
    (
    group,
    "The Comic Corner",
    ""
),
    (
    group,
    "Home Alone",
    ""
),
    (
    group,
    "Romantic Movies",
    ""
),
    (
    group,
    "Thriller Movies",
    ""
),
    (
    group,
    Badminton,
    ""
),
    (
    group,
    "Celebrity Gossip",
    ""
),
    (
    group,
    "Dark Night",
    ""
),
    (
    group,
    "Graphics Designer",
    ""
),
    (
    group,
    "I Just Wanna....",
    ""
),
    (
    group,
    Religion,
    ""
),
    (
    group,
    "English Movies",
    ""
),
    (
    group,
    "Music World",
    ""
),
    (
    group,
    "Actions Movies",
    ""
),
    (
    group,
    "Bed & Breakfast",
    ""
),
    (
    group,
    "Strategic Games",
    ""
),
    (
    group,
    "Beer Lovers",
    ""
),
    (
    group,
    Hackers,
    ""
),
    (
    group,
    "Darkroom-Darkroom",
    ""
),
    (
    group,
    "Arcade Games",
    ""
),
    (
    group,
    "Hindi Movies",
    ""
),
    (
    mood,
    Anxious,
    1386749684146
),
    (
    "profilepic_time",
    1386545975408
),
    (
    "status_msg",
    " *z32_ hell0",
    1386635654457
),
    (
    Broadcast,
    3,
    11,
    1372945566365
),
    (
    Broadcast,
    3,
    11,
    3
),
    (
    Broadcast,
    3,
    11,
    3
),
    (
    Broadcast,
    3,
    11,
    1372858799160
),
    (
    Broadcast,
    6,
    11,
    1372920363550
),
    (
    Broadcast,
    6,
    30,
    1373012360303
),
    (
    Broadcast,
    6,
    30,
    1373015204935
),
    (
    Broadcast,
    6,
    30,
    1373018547181
),
    (
    Broadcast,
    6,
    30,
    1373018768064
),
    (
    Broadcast,
    7,
    37,
    1373025360112
),
    (
    Broadcast,
    3,
    37,
    1373031270639
),
    (
    Broadcast,
    3,
    42,
    1373868972980
),
    (
    Broadcast,
    3,
    29,
    1372936645430
),
    (
    Broadcast,
    3,
    29,
    1372935983470
),
    (
    Broadcast,
    3,
    101,
    1374150527293
),
    (
    bulletin,
    "dbxjsbxdijxjdjxichdjdixhdbdjx hdjdbdh",
    1382331040766
),
    (
    bulletin,
    "aaabbb ccc dddd eee ffff",
    1382510132316
),
    (
    bulletin,
    "dvxishhxxbbosihdjxibididhxososjshsisos dijfjeosksn osjdjkd",
    1382510521856
),
    (
    bulletin,
    tsotdo,
    1382707279159
),
    (
    bulletin,
    84saurzuzri,
    1382707293764
),
    (
    bulletin,
    aiaktsktzyodld,
    1382707305875
),
    (
    bulletin,
    uarsistoso,
    1382707326326
),
    (
    bulletin,
    2e58e8etisististi,
    1382707335278
),
    (
    bulletin,
    ztkzktzgtkktotk,
    1382707484453
),
    (
    bulletin,
    ztkzktzgtkktotk9e85a4a47a48a37ariz,
    1382707491619
),
    (
    bulletin,
    "dbxidj didcxj",
    1384173984019
),
    (
    bulletin,
    "testing testing testing testing",
    1384589761276
),
    (
    bulletin,
    "testing testing testing testing",
    1384589772960
),
    (
    bulletin,
    "testing testing testing testing",
    1384589788706
),
    (
    bulletin,
    "testing testing testing testing",
    1384589822861
),
    (
    bulletin,
    "testing testing testing testing",
    1384589871332
),
    (
    bulletin,
    "testing testing testing testing",
    1384589875364
),
    (
    bulletin,
    "testing testing testing testing",
    1384589910927
),
    (
    bulletin,
    hey,
    1384589984774
),
    (
    bulletin,
    "heya ",
    1384590016235
),
    (
    bulletin,
    ok,
    1384597237610
),
    (
    bulletin,
    "hey ",
    1384605812061
),
    (
    bulletin,
    fhjfs,
    1384757502287
),
```

There is timestamp for some array and no timestamp for some array

It is very complex for me. Can any one help me with that 
Thanks

Comment: Look at any of the "sortedArrayUsing..." methods of NSArray, and the "sortUsing...: methods of NSMutableArray.  I usually find it simplest for my flaky brain to use the "...UsingFunction" flavor and define a C-style function for the comparator, but others like the fancy block stuff.

Comment: it is not sorting from the soring methods given in nsmutable array. I think we have to manually sort it.but i couldn't find vthe  exact logic to work it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a custom comparator block, like this (you'll need to adjust the indices according to your data structure):

```
NSArray *array = @[@[@"a", @456], @[@"b", @123], @[@"c", @""]];

NSArray *sorted = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSArray *a, NSArray *b) {
  if ([a.lastObject isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]] &&
      [b.lastObject isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
    return [a.lastObject compare:b.lastObject];
  }
  return NSOrderedAscending;
}];

NSLog(@"%@", sorted);
```

You can change `NSOrderedAscending` to `NSOrderedDescending` if you want the non-timestamped records to appear before the timestamped ones.

In addition, I recommend you to avoid storing your data in `NSArray` of `NSArray`s, and create a proper [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) (that can define it's own sorting function, if needed) for your items.

Comment: it is sorting but i dont know what paramemeter it is taking for sorting the sorted string is in my next comment

Comment: (
        group,
        "Celebrity Gossip",
        "checkin_place",
        ""
    ),
        (
        bulletin,
        "testing testing testing testing",
        "checkin_place",
        1384589875364
    ),
        (
        Broadcast,
        3,
        29,
        1372936645430
    ),
        (
        group,
        "Actions Movies",
        "checkin_place",
        ""
    ),
        (
        Broadcast,
        6,
        30,
        1373018768064
    ),
        (
        group,
        "Dark Night",
        "checkin_place",
        ""
    ),

Comment: how can i sort it properly for  date please help me

Comment: I see that various records have different number of elements. Do you have any promise on where the timestamp is, and how to know if a timestamp doesn't exist in a record?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, then the last object is either `""` or the timestamp itself. I've edited my answer according to that guess.

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly compared the pointers and not the objects themselves. See the updated answer.